# How to use variable as secret key in express-session's session object

Tags: node.js, express-session

I have an express.js file which requires config.js which loads development.js. Now I want to use secret as a variable in session object of express-session. I will give you a quick breakup of how I had setup my code so far.

Config folder

```
 Env

   -- development.js
```

-- config.js

-- express.js

**Development.js**

```
module.exports = function(){
 sessionSecret: 'developmentSessionSecret'
}
```

**Config.js**

```
module.exports = require('./env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js' );
```

** Express.js **

```
var config = require('./config'),
session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    secret: config.sessionSecret
}));
```

**The problem** is that console.log(config.sessionSecret) is *undefined*. 
  Why this is not working and what will be the correct way to set up ?

Comment: module.exports = require('./env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js' )();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `development.js` is exporting a constructor function which you never call (and it doesn't return anything either).

Based on the syntax you used in the callers, you probably meant for `development.js` to be this:

```
module.exports = {
    sessionSecret: 'developmentSessionSecret'
}
```

where it just exports a static object that can be directly used by the rest of your code.